# Check if all characters are uppercase in string - Obj C

Tags: objective-c, string

I know I can check if a string *contains* uppercase letters but is there some built in function in Objective-C to check if *all* characters are uppercase letters? I want to avoid looping through each character to see if it contains a lowercase letter and then break out of the loop if it contains one as this takes up more memory and takes more time. Time is a constraint as I have to process thousands of strings.

Comment: "I want to avoid looping through each character" -- how else would the computer possibly do it? And what makes you think this "takes up more memory"?

Comment: @KurtRevis I don't feel like refuting that but it's pretty obvious, especially with Objective-C's strange methods.

Comment: No, it isn't "pretty obvious" at all. How does looping over every character, and calling `-[NSString characterAtIndex:]`, "take up" any memory at all? It wouldn't create any objects and wouldn't need to allocate any memory.

Comment: I have updated my answer. May be new code will be more suitable for purposes.

Comment: Iterating is most efficient here, won't cost you *any* memory allocation, and can break on the very first non-uppercase character.

Comment: Another aspect is that checking a single character for being uppercase is not trivial unless you restrict yourself to the ASCII character set. But what about Ψ or д?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative approach that might appeal given your concerns: Use `NSString`'s `rangeOfCharactersFromSet:` passing it `NSCharacterSet`'s `lowercaseLetterCharacterSet`. If this finds anything then the string isn't all uppercase. It's a single line expression like the other current answers, but doesn't involve creating an uppercase copy of the string and works for all Unicode letters.

Comment: This fails if any of the characters aren't alphanumeric.

Comment: @NSResponder - Depends... The question wasn't clear if the string should only contain uppercase, or whether the letters in it should be uppercase (the answer given here as spaces, punctuation, digits etc. are probably OK). You just need to construct the the appropriate set, e.g. using `uppercaseLetterCharacterSet` and `inverseSet` can be used to test for nothing but uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 NSString * myString;

    [myString.uppercaseString isEqualToString:myString];
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I didn't think of NSString properties.

Comment: This will allocate a lot of memory (a whole new string), iterate over every character in the original string, upper-case it, and  *then* compare it to the original string. This would actually use more memory, and be less efficient, than simply iterating over the characters in the original string.

Comment: Yea, you are right but as mentioned in question there is a lot of strings, and iteration can get less memory but more CPU time vs allocating memory that will be deallocated at end of scope.

Comment: Most probably this will be in every way (RAM and CPU) less efficient than just iterating the characters itself. And it will allocate memory and convert the whole string, even if the first character is lowercase. If using within a huge loop, you surely don't want to forget an autorelease pool in place. 
The good thing about it is the fast implementation - just takes one line. Actually, in *most* cases this is just the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

```
[your_string.uppercaseString isEqualToString:your_string];
```

If you need to process a lot of strings, especially long string may be following code will be faster

```
// In case you need process a lo of strings this set should be initialized before loop!
NSCharacterSet *set = [NSCharacterSet lowercaseLetterCharacterSet];

// check for allowed characters
BOOL isValid = ([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location == NSNotFound);
```

Comment: Note that the first option creates a new string, something OP wants to avoid.

Comment: @Josh Caswell, yes. And this was the reason I have added the second variant.

Comment: NSCharacterSet already has pre-defined uppercase and lowercase sets.

Answer (score 0):

```
@implementation NSString (uppercaseOnly)

 - (BOOL) allUpperCase {
return [self rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[[NSCharacterSet upperCaseLetterCharacterSet] invertedSet]].location == NSNotFound;
}
```